# Linux Mint suddenly not loading GUI

Tags: linux-mint

I was using Linux Mint 18.1 just fine last week. 
When I turned my laptop today, the headphones were not working. Later, some keyboard functions, as lock screen shortcut also was not working.

Then I restarted the OS and when it came back, it was totally messed. There is no title bar, no panel (task bar).

Is there anything I can do, mostly by command line, to repair this?

EDIT: desktop environments available are cinnamon2d, cinnamon and xfce.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply try to reinstall graphical environment.

1 - start a new tty and log in as your user:

```
CTRL + ALT + F3
```

2 - update apt cache:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
```

3 - reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $your_graphical_environment_pkg_name
```

e.g.: $your_graphical_environment_pkg_name = gnome